# ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium webdriver python binding with the `unittest` framework. My tests start failing when I repeat them. There are about 100 test cases in my suite.

After looping them three times the error message below appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):          
File "TestPlan.py", line 26, in setUp  
self.driver=self.OpenBrowser(self.configDic['BrowserOption='])
File "D:\AutoTest-Selenium\Controller.py", line 85, in OpenBrowser
File "C:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__   
WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.  
Please download from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html               
and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver'
```

my `setUp` class and `tearDown` methods are as follows:

```
def setUp(self):            
    self.driver=self.OpenBrowser(self.configDic['BrowserOption=']) 

def tearDown(self): 
    self.driver.quit()
```

I also found some Chromedriver processes in my task manager. Is this why the error message shows up? I've been paying attention to close every webdriver instance after using them. Is there any workaround for this situation?

Thank you guys for help.

Comment: Whats the error msg and stack?

Comment: @bcar This question seems unsolvable. Found the similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220856/selenium-crashes-after-running-around-500-tests)

Comment: I am trying to detail exactly how this bug occurs; Are you running these tests with nose? If not, how are you "repeating" these tests?

Answer (score 1):

Had **"ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path."** error on Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Solved this way:

```
sudo -i
wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.15/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /usr/local/bin
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question and later comments indicate you can run almost 300 tests (proving chromedriver IS in your PATH) I am guessing the problem is two-fold:

1. selenium <= 2.44.0 has a bug that hides the actual error messages from you; that is, the error *ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path* is bogus.
2. If that bug didn't exist, it may well tell you **Too many open files**.

See my [more detailed StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28520062/58371) about the root issues involved. To fix the problem:

- Increase max # of open files **... OR ...**
- Add calls to close `stdout` and `stderr` in

  `site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py`

```python
try:
    if self.process:
        self.process.stdout.close()  # <-- add this line
        self.process.stderr.close()  # <-- and this one
        self.process.kill()
        self.process.wait()
except OSError:
    # kill may not be available under windows environment
    pass
```

Comment: fwiw, this answer is no longer relevant.  the code in service.py has been refactored and fixed so it doesn't leak file handles.